# How can I fix CSS not being applied correctly?

Tags: html, css

My website is displaying all of its CSS properly with the exception of two sections of HTML. I have two divs with the same class name that are not having the appropriate CSS applied. The CSS is applied when I test the site on my local host, but it magically vanishes when I push the updated to the live site, even though the linked CSS sheet contains the proper code.

I'm hosting my site through BlueHost. I've uploaded an index.html file, a .css file, and some images. Everything else came stock in the webroot directory and is working properly.

I've tried renaming the class name and re-publishing the .css file.

/* This set of CSS doesn't get applied on the live site. */

```
.buttonSection {

 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 margin: 10px auto;
 width: 80%;
 }
```

```css
.buttons {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  flex-grow: 3;
}

.buttons a {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.logos {
  height: 4vh;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.buttonSection {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonSection">

  <div class="buttons" id="call">
    <a href="tel:111-111-1111">
      <img class="logos" src="\call.png"> Call Me</a>
  </div>

  <div class="buttons" id="text">
    <a href="sms:111-111-1111">
      <img class="logos" src="\text.png"> Text Me</a>
  </div>

  <div class="buttons" id="email">
    <a href="mailto:hello@gmail.com">
      <img class="logos" src="\email.png"> Email Me</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm expecting the button divs to be aligned in a row.

I use the inspect tool on Google Chrome to test if the code is applied and the "element.style{}" section shows that there is no code being applied. When I put the code I listed above in this section I see the desired results.

Comment: can you provide your live website link? So we can check. There has to be a linking problem.

Comment: The `element.style` shows css applied directly to the element (through `style=` attribute). Below that should be another section with `.buttonSection{}` styles, if there isn't check whether the `div` element has the correct class or not. Copying your code to jsfiddle shows it works as expected though, the buttons are in a row, so most likely you have a syntax error somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your code… Actually, your flexbox works well. There isn't an issue here. This error must come from another area.

```css
.buttonSection {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 margin: 10px auto;
 width: 80%;
}

.buttons {.buttonSection {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 margin: 10px auto;
 width: 80%;
}

.buttons {
 padding: 5px;
 border: 1px solid;
 flex-grow: 3;
}

.buttons a {
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
}

.logos {
 height: 4vh;
 margin-left: 15px;
}

 padding: 5px;
 border: 1px solid;
 flex-grow: 3;
}

.buttons a {
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
}

.logos {
 height: 4vh;
 margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonSection">

 <div class="buttons"  id="call">
<a href="tel:111-111-1111">
<img class="logos" src="\call.png">
  Call Me</a>
</div>

<div class="buttons"  id="text">
 <a href="sms:111-111-1111">
  <img class="logos" src="\text.png">
  Text Me</a>
</div>

<div class="buttons"  id="email">
<a href="mailto:hello@gmail.com">
  <img class="logos" src="\email.png">
  Email Me</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code shouldn't be an issue as far as I can see.
Maybe try CTR+F5 (hard reload) on the page and make sure your project is saved.
This should reload all the sources of the page including your CSS file(s) and it clears your cache for your test domain/localhost.